# am trying to bring in empty cells from POI. Even an example on how to bring in a value from a spreadsheet would be very helpful

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am looking for empty cells in a spreadsheet. Just empty cells i have the code already written but I am having problems with the if statement i am not sure how to check for an empty cell

```
 public class Parse {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String splitBy = ",";  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newFileReader("/Users/Adrian/Dropbox/Tedds/TestBeam.csv"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

         String[] a = line.split(splitBy);
         String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
         String[] h = line.split(splitBy);
         String[] i = line.split(splitBy); // is 8 in 

         if(s.contains((" ")){
             System.out.println("Error");}

         System.out.println("Checked By " + h[7] + ",");  }
         br.close();
 }}
```

Even an example on how to bring in a value from a spreadsheet would be very helpful just to see how to go about it

Comment: can you specify what problem you are facing?

Comment: it is the if statement i do not know what to write for it to check for an empty cell

Comment: if you debug or print the value of `s` what does it show?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 s cannot be resolved

 at Parse.main(Parse.java:22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have copied the code from somewhere. Also I don't see any POI code within your example

You don't need to call split multiple times. 
Loop over the array `a` for each string `s` in this array check if the value is empty

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

 String[] a = line.split(splitBy);
 for(String s: a){
    if(s!=null && !s.trim().isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("Error");
    }
 }

 System.out.println("Checked By " + a[7] + ",");

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help its very appreciated. I tried the code and this came up. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at Parse.main(Parse.java:26)                                       any ideas?

Comment: The error tells what the issue is. There isn't any object at index 7. So `a[7]` at last line would not work. I just copied it from above question. You yourself need to identify the index that you want and fix accordingly